# Looking to combine multiple rows of data based on common column data

Tags: r, preprocessor

I'm looking at trying to merge two consecutive rows of data using common column(s) data. In essence I'm trying to go from

```
 UserID Geography   Login  Logout

   user1  East      0:00:22    -       
   user1  East         -     0:01:29
   user2  West      0:03:57    -    
   user2  West         -     0:48:10
   user3  South     0:59:25    -    
   user3  South        -     1:08:21
```

to

```
  UserID Geography   Login  Logout

   user1  East      0:00:22  0:01:29       
   user2  West      0:03:57  0:48:10    
   user3  South     0:59:25  1:08:21
```

My apologies in advance for the formatting. I wanted to mention that there are multiple rows like this containing user1,user2 etc's data so an aggregation function such as MAX or MIN would not work. Also the solution I'm looking for is in R but any other language would also be most welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Gopal

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with the **dplyr** and **tidyr** packages. In essence, we gather the login and logout times into a single column, remove empty values, and re-spread login and logout events into their own columns.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 'UserID Geography   Login  Logout

              user1  East      0:00:22    -       
              user1  East         -     0:01:29
              user2  West      0:03:57    -    
              user2  West         -     0:48:10
              user3  South     0:59:25    -    
              user3  South        -     1:08:21', header = T)

  UserID Geography   Login  Logout
1  user1      East 0:00:22       -
2  user1      East       - 0:01:29
3  user2      West 0:03:57       -
4  user2      West       - 0:48:10
5  user3     South 0:59:25       -
6  user3     South       - 1:08:21

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  gather(action, time, -UserID, -Geography) %>% 
  filter(time != '-') %>% 
  spread(action, time)

  UserID Geography   Login  Logout
1  user1      East 0:00:22 0:01:29
2  user2      West 0:03:57 0:48:10
3  user3     South 0:59:25 1:08:21
```

#### Handling multiple sessions

In the OP's original data set, multiple logins per user are possible:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'UserID Geography   EventType ChannelType   Time 
user4   South   Log-in  Web 0:00:10 
user1   East    Log-in  Web 0:00:22 
user4   South   Log-out Mobile  0:00:44 
user1   East    Log-out Web 0:01:29 
user5   East    Log-in  Web 0:02:01 
user1   East    Log-in  Mobile 0:03:57 
user16  South   Log-in  Mobile  0:04:36 
user15  North   Log-in  Mobile  0:05:42 
user3   North   Log-in  Web 0:05:59 
user8   South   Log-in  Mobile  0:07:09 
user19  North   Log-in  Mobile  0:09:22 
user11  North   Log-in  Web 0:12:39 
user8   South   Log-out Web 0:18:32 
user8   South   Log-in  Web 0:19:35', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The key is to use **dplyr** to group logins and logout per user, then number these. With each login/logout pairing now uniquely identified, the data can be reformatted:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  arrange(UserID, Time) %>% 
  group_by(UserID, EventType) %>% 
  mutate(EventNum = 1:n()) %>% 
  select(-ChannelType) %>% 
  spread(EventType, Time, fill = '-') %>% 
  arrange(`Log-in`)

   UserID Geography EventNum `Log-in` `Log-out`
    <chr>     <chr>    <int>    <chr>     <chr>
 1  user4     South        1  0:00:10   0:00:44
 2  user1      East        1  0:00:22   0:01:29
 3  user5      East        1  0:02:01         -
 4  user1      East        2  0:03:57         -
 5 user16     South        1  0:04:36         -
 6 user15     North        1  0:05:42         -
 7  user3     North        1  0:05:59         -
 8  user8     South        1  0:07:09   0:18:32
 9 user19     North        1  0:09:22         -
10 user11     North        1  0:12:39         -
11  user8     South        2  0:19:35         -
```

Comment: Thank you @jdobres for the prompt response. I was skeptical if I presented the problem statement correctly or not but you have understood it exactly right. I tried this out and it gives me a different error stated below:                                                                                        Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2, 3...32, 33, 34), (380, 381, 382, ... 402, 403, 404), ...                                                                          I believe this is due to the duplicate values in UserID and Geography columns. Would there be a way around this?

Comment: Is it possible for a given user to have multiple login/logout times? If so, please provide an example of what this looks like in your data set.

Comment: Thanks again for responding back. Here's how the data originally looked like UserID Geography EventType ChannelType Time
user4 South Log-in Web 0:00:10
user1 East Log-in Web 0:00:22
user4 South Log-out Mobile 0:00:44
user1 East Log-out Web 0:01:29
user5 East Log-in Web 0:02:01
user1 East Log-in Mobile 0:03:57
user16 South Log-in Mobile 0:04:36
user15 North Log-in Mobile 0:05:42
user3 North Log-in Web 0:05:59
user8 South Log-in Mobile 0:07:09
user19 North Log-in Mobile 0:09:22
user11 North Log-in Web 0:12:39
user8 South Log-out Web 0:18:32
user8 South Log-in Web 0:19:35

Comment: My apologies again for the format. I wanted to clarify that there were 5 columns in the original dataset i.e. UserID, Geography, EventType, ChannelType and Time. EventType is either Log-in or Log-out and the time is the time of the activity (either login or logout). I've got the data from this to the format I mentioned in my question. Its the final stage of data pre processing that I'm struggling with. I can confirm the error is with the final command of spread(action, time).

Comment: Thanks again @jdobres for taking the time out and answering this. I see the code working perfectly with the top part (head) of the dataset but some issues seen with the tail or the end of the dataset. However, let me try to understand what could be causing this and get back. Once again many thanks for spending time on this.